# Add 10 more days to new Date Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm getting the date to this format like this: `12.12.2023` with this function:

```js
var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
```

And what I want to do is for example, add more 10 days to it. for example, if it is: `12.12.2023` to be `22.12.2023`

Answer (score 0):

```
let days = 10;
today.setDate(today.getDate() + days);
```